# How to handle mapping of generated classes with identical fields?

Tags: java

We have a large number of classes that is generated by JAXB.  There are a couple that have identical fields and I want to see if there is a clean way to map class A to class B.

Example:

```java
public static class ParentA  implements ... {

   public static class A implements ... {
      protected String name;
   }
}
```

```java
public static class ParentB  implements ... {

   public static class B implements ... {
      protected String name;
   }
}
```

I want to take an incoming `A` and map it to `B` but there are many other classes that I want to map `A` to.  How can I handle this?  I see that there is a `copyTo` method, but it only copies `A` to another `A`.

Comment: I also would like to know if there is a way to wrap these generated classes with a builder pattern.

Comment: Is there a superclass of both A and B? If not, why do they have so much in common without being related? Its hard to say what you want to model and how this could be solved without knowing more about your domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'd probably get some value from would be an Object mapping tool/framework. The point of such tools is to remove some boilerplate code, so that you don't have to do so much work to transform object A into object B, in your scenerio. However, these are tool recommendations and not such a great fit for this site. You should check out http://modelmapper.org/ and google around for some similar packages.

Answer (score 0):

If all that A and B have in common is the field name, and all you want is an extended version of

```
B b = new B();
b.setName(a.getName());
```

You could consider a bean mapping tool like [Dozer.](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer)